# How to pass json obj value to API in angular (for post method)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular4-httpclient

Here i am trying to post some data to API.but it does not work.because i have got 400 bad request.i think my service or typescript is not fine.when trying to postman I got the output.so i confirm my Web APi is working fine. actually I am new in angular.so please helpme for this i am a beginner.i search so many times here but didn't get the answer. here my api is accepting value by json obj
like (Note i am using angular4 web Api)

```
{ 
 "Header": {

        "UserID": 6,
       "created": "February 4, 2016 10:13:00",
        ....etc........
     },

  "detail": [
{

  "ShopID": 1,
 "ItemID": 126,
.....etc.........
  },
  {     
 "ShopID": 1,
 "ItemID": 127,
.....etc.........
 }
 ]
 }
```

but my datas are passing to API is like (so i think this is the problem)

```
    [{
  "userid": "64",
  "created": "February 4, 2016 10:13:00",
  "CompanyID": "1",
  "modified": "February 4, 2016 10:13:00",
  "modifieduserid": "65",
  "confirm": "true",
  "ShopId": 1,
  "TransactionId": 1,
   "shopid": 12,
  "Itemid": 12928,
  "PackingTypeID": 3,
  "Itemcode": "124018",
  "Itemdescription": "COTTON GLOVES 350G",
  "PackingtypeName": "12 PCS",
  "Stockcount": 12
```

}
]

**And this is my ts file**

```
     stockitems: IStockCountHeaders[] = [];   
 items: IStockCountHeaders;
  stockdetail: IStockdetails[] = [];

  addItems(value: any) {
this.items = new IStockCountHeaders(this.userid, this.created, t this.confirm,this.shopid, 
 value.ItemID, value.PackingTypeID, value.ItemCode, value.ItemDescription, 
 value.PackingtypeName, 
    value.Stock,
   );
this.stockitems.push(this.items);
  }
onclick(){
 this._enqService.CatchStockDetailHeader(this.stockitems)
    .subscribe(value => {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value != null) {
            value.forEach(items => {
                this.stockitems.push(this.items)
            });
        }
    },
        error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
        });
 }
```

**this is my angular service file**

```
          CatchStockDetailHeader(stock: any)
    : Observable<IStockCountHeaders[]> {
    let IStockCounts = stock;  
    console.log(IStockCounts)
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    headers.append('userid', IStockCounts.userid);
    headers.append('created', IStockCounts.created);
    headers.append('.CompanyID', IStockCounts.CompanyID);
    headers.append('modified', IStockCounts.modified);
    headers.append('modifieduserid', IStockCounts.modifieduserid);
    headers.append('confirm', IStockCounts.confirm);    
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:3071/api/Stockcountheader/' + 'Stock', IStockCounts, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <IStockCountHeaders[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a cross domain request because you are posting to localhost:3071 and you usually host the Angular app on localhost:4200.

The two option are to either add an allow all header from the api or to use a proxy.

To allow cross domain request from your api add the header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

on the server.

To use a proxy create a file called proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3071/api/",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and serve with

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

And instead of using

```
http://localhost:3071/api/
```

use

```
/api/
```

Comment: but here i am using visual studio 2015 so i would not use cmd in this project

Comment: but in another function i use same post method its work fine

Comment: I would suggest to by setting proxy itself!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale how to setting proxy ?

Comment: @BrockJames check the answer